# Menor Data em um conjunto de dados

Tags: r

Tenho um conjunto de dados e gostaria de selecionar apenas a menor data  entre cada chave primária (coluna `MATRICULA`). Segue o exemplo do meu DF:

```
MATRICULA <- c(1,1,3,3,3,4,5,5,5,5,6)
DATA <- c('15/01/2018', '10/12/2017', '20/11/2017', '01/01/2015', 
  '25/10/2018', '02/07/2016', '03/12/2016','17/08/2017', '22/03/2018', 
  '12/06/2018', '13/04/2014')
DADOS <- data.frame(MATRICULA, DATA)
```

Já utilizo a função `abv_data = c(as.Date(DADOS$DATA,"%d/%m/%Y"))` para transformar o formato da data.

Portanto, gostaria que o resultado aparecesse apenas a menor data a partir da coluna `MATRICULA`. O resultado que espero deve ser:

```
MATRICULA <- c(1,3,4,5,6)
DATA <- c('10/12/2017', '01/01/2015', '02/07/2016', '03/12/2016', '13/04/2014')
DADOS <- data.frame(MATRICULA,DATA)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Este problema é bem fácil de resolver utilizando o pacote `dplyr`. A primeira coisa a se fazer é transformar a coluna `DATA` em data, para que o `R` consiga estabelecer uma relação de ordem para ela. Eu vou apenas copiar o teu código original, que estava correto, e sobrescrever a coluna `DATA` dentro de `DADOS`:

```
DADOS$DATA = c(as.Date(DADOS$DATA,"%d/%m/%Y"))
```

Com isso feito, o pacote `dplyr` vai servir para agruparmos os teus dados por `MATRICULA` e, a seguir, procurar o menor valor de `DATA` para cada uma delas:

```
DADOS %>% 
  group_by(MATRICULA) %>% 
  slice(which.min(DATA))
# A tibble: 5 x 2
# Groups:   MATRICULA [5]
  MATRICULA DATA      
      <dbl> <date>    
1         1 2017-12-10
2         3 2015-01-01
3         4 2016-07-02
4         5 2016-12-03
5         6 2014-04-13
```

E pronto. Esta aí o resultado. Ele vai servir para qualquer número de matrículas que tu tiver no teu conjunto de dados, e não vai importar quantas datas existem dentro de cada uma destas matrículas.

Answer (score 6):

Duas maneiras com R base.

Com `aggregate`.

```
aggregate(abv_data ~ MATRICULA, DADOS, min)
#  MATRICULA   abv_data
#1         1 2017-12-10
#2         3 2015-01-01
#3         4 2016-07-02
#4         5 2016-12-03
#5         6 2014-04-13
```

Com `tapply`.

```
as.Date(tapply(abv_data, DADOS$MATRICULA, FUN = min), origin = "1970-01-01")
#           1            3            4            5            6 
#"2017-12-10" "2015-01-01" "2016-07-02" "2016-12-03" "2014-04-13"
```

Answer (score 5):

Uma outra solução com `dplyr` é usando `filter` ao invés do `slice`.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

DADOS %>% 
  mutate(DATA = dmy(as.character(DATA))) %>% 
  group_by(MATRICULA) %>% 
  filter(DATA == min(DATA))

# A tibble: 5 x 2
# Groups:   MATRICULA [5]
  MATRICULA DATA      
      <dbl> <date>    
1         1 2017-12-10
2         3 2015-01-01
3         4 2016-07-02
4         5 2016-12-03
5         6 2014-04-13
```

Comment: Funcionou melhor dessa forma. Como tenho um DF de milhões de linhas, pelo aggregate não tive sucesso.